# Change Highcharts sparklines marker colours

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

How can I colour the markers in a Highcharts Sparkline? Below has no effect, the markers all stay in their default blue colour.

```
var $sparkline = $('.sparkline'),
    colors = ['red','green','blue','green','red'],
    data = [10,20,30,40,50];

$sparkline.highcharts('SparkLine', {
    series: [{
        data: data
    }],
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            marker: {
                fillColor: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return colors[this.x];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    chart: {}
});
```

Comment: Why is there a `formatter` inside your `fillColor`? What are you trying to achieve? Why not just set `fillColor: 'red'` or similar.

Comment: [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.marker.fillColor) reference: `fillColor: Color` -> `fillColor` should be string, containing color. There's not such thing like conditional formatting using formatters (?).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a way to target that particular aspect of the chart, but the blue colour used is the default, first colour in the chart's main `colors` array (`#7cb5ec`). This is configured via the `colors` property (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#colors):

```
$sparkline.highcharts('SparkLine', {
    colors: [ ... ],
    series: [{
        data: data
    }],
    ...
});
```

To change it to red as an example, you'd simply place `'#f00'` as the first item in the array:

```
$sparkline.highcharts('SparkLine', {
    colors: [ '#f00' ],
    ...
});
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9xLu1dhb/).